# Calling my own DLL from Azure Function, supported .NET Framework versions

Tags: azure, f#, azure-functions

What's the highest .NET Framework version I can compile my dll (it's F# of course)? If it's 4.6, does that mean I can compile under 4.6.1, 4.6.2? I already tried 4.6.1. Maybe that works and my problemes are related to my next question:

I've tried putting the dll and dependent files in in myFunction/bin/myDll/*.* and currently referenced by

```
\#r "bin/myDll/myDll.dll"
```

in the function, which according to [Reference c# class library in my Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115588/reference-c-sharp-class-library-in-my-azure-function) should work.

This also doesn't seem to work. I would prefer a bin at the app service level so all my functions could reference the same dlls.

Am I missing a binding in the function.json? It would be nice if you could put such settings at the app service level in either settings.json or host.json

I'm looking for both the answer to the technical question, and where is it documented?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference c# class library in my Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115588/reference-c-sharp-class-library-in-my-azure-function)

Comment: @Mikhail the linked answer does not address the supported .NET Framework versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see the .NET Framework version in `Application settings` tab of your Function App (it's 4.7 now):

[image: Function App Application settings]

Referencing custom assemblies, including sharing references between several functions, is described in [Referencing custom assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-custom-assemblies).

If you put `myDll.dll` into `bin` folder of your function, you can just reference it by `#r "myDll.dll"` (no `bin` in here).

On a final note, I would suggest you using [precompiled functions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Precompiled-functions) for any functions which require multiple assemblies to be deployed.

Comment: you're the second person to recommend precompiled. I'm giving up the script. It is too frustrating, but I'll mark yours as the answer.