# Reference dll in my precompiled C# Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

In reference to [Reference c# class library in my Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115588/reference-c-sharp-class-library-in-my-azure-function) I would like to ask the same question how to achieve this
 - with a precompiled C# Azure function
 - with any kind of .dll (that is provided as such, thus not a NuGet)
 - within VS Code

AFAIK this is not documented

Answer (score 2):

Add a folder like `MyAssemblies` containing our dlls under function app folder.

Then add references in `functionappname.csproj`.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="MyCustomDll">
      <HintPath>./MyAssemblies/MyCustomDll.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```